# Car A has higher power, but car B has higher torque. Which one would win in a straight drag race?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, power

Suppose we have 2 cars with different specifications.
Car A has a higher power specification but  a lower torque specification.
Car B has a higher torque specification but  a lower power specification.

Suppose they enter a drag race on a flat, straight track. Who will win the race?

Comment: [The Great Torque vs. Horsepower Debate](https://www.streetmusclemag.com/tech-stories/torque-vs-horsepower/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Who will win the race ?

It depends.

Depending on the other specifications, namely

1. the exact torque/power curves and
2. the geartrain ratios of each car,

you could have car A win or car B win.

First of all, just to get something out of the way, because this question seems to be intended to ask, "which is better higher power or higher torque?". That question does not make a lot of sense, because the power and torque of a car engine are not independent of each other. Both have a strict relation between them. Given the power curve of any engine, you can calculate its torque curve and vice versa.

### The peak power/torque is less important than power/torque CURVE

Regarding the specific example you have asked about, one thing to understand is that the specified power and torque of an engine are generally the peak power and peak torque. The engine, in general would not produce that power or that torque throughout its operating rpm range. So, the cars would neither produce the same power, or the same torque from start of race to end of race.

What is more important is the power/torque CURVE, which tells us the torque/power produced by the engine at each value of rpm, rather than peak torque/power. One car may have a higher peak value, but that peak value could be concentrated only at a specific rpm, while the other car might have a lower peak value but it could be across a broader rpm range, so that, at most of the rpm range, it would have higher value than the other car, even though it's peak value might be lower.
As can be seen by the diagram i am borrowing from Knight watch's answer

[image]

The red car engine has higher peak power, but the blue car engine has higher power in the rpm range of 0-5000.
Similarly, when it comes to torque, the blue car engine has higher peak torque, but the red car engine has higher torque in the rpm range of 5000 and above.

This diagram is just an example, and the car with higher peak value might still be faster . But, in general, only the peak value does not tell the whole story, without knowing the value over a range of rpms.

So, the specification of peak power/torque is not the only thing which would determine the winner. Power/torque over a range of rpm also matters.

### The role of the gearbox

The other important deciding factor would be the gear ratios used. These will determine which car will be better able to stay at its peak operating rpm for most of the race.

### Race distance matters as well

One more factor that would matter is the length of the race. A shorter race could favor one car, whereas the other car could win in a longer race.

So to summarize, just comparing peak power or peak torque would not give an answer as to who will win.

To get the answer, you need to know

1. the power/torque curve of each car
2. the gear ratios of each car
3. the distance of the track from start to finish
   (assuming of course that other things like weight of car etc. are equal).

Comment: Many good aspects in this answer, but the key ingredient is missing: The gearbox. With correct gearing, it doesn't matter how fast the engine needs to rotate to deliver max power, the gearbox will convert the RPMs into the max amount of torque.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I HAVE mentioned the important role of the gearbox in the last part of the answer. That is why, we cannot say who will win, without knowing what are the gear ratios used .  IF both cars used a theoretically perfect gear box, that is ALWAYS able to keep each car at the rpm where it delivers max power, THEN the higher powered car will win. But real world gearboxes do not achieve that kind of perfection. They have to make trade offs . Hence, in real world cars, the gearbox used AND the actual engine curves can swing the race between one car or the other.

Comment: You mention it in passing, burried deep towards the end of the question. That's as good as if it were not there at all. Instead, what a reader picks up is all the stuff about torque curves which is only interesting to the gear box designer. In the end product, a car with engine and gearbox, the gearbox is designed to make the best use of the torque curve that the motor provides. As such, it is pretty pointless to talk about the torque of a car's engine, the only relevant fact of the engine is its power, and for the car you need to add how well designed its gear box is.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica " _it is pretty pointless to talk about the torque of a car's engine, the only relevant fact of the engine is its power_ " Not true. Torque and power are not independent.  What is relevant is the power/torque CURVE. That tells us over how broad a range of RPM it produces that power/torque. The single number of torque or power only tells us the peak value, which is less relevant than the value over a range of rpms. I take the point about the formatting of the answer . I will try and edit it to mention the gearbox more prominently

Comment: The actual power/torque curve is only relevant to the gear box designer: It tells them how many gears are needed to cover a given range of speeds with a certain minimum power at the wheels. To the car driver, the only difference is in how often they need to shift gears. Or, if the shifting happens automatically (like in a double clutch setup), it's totally irrelevant, they just step on it and the engine/transmission deliver what they are designed to deliver. In all cases, the power at the wheels only depends on the engine's max power, not the engine's max torque.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica " _the power at the wheels only depends on the engine's max power, not the engine's max torque_ " Not true. That would be the case, if you had a perfectly ideal gearbox, that was able to keep the engine at the max power rpm all the time. In the real world, there are no such gearboxes. At each shift of the gear, the rpm changes , so the rpm does not stay at the max power level all the time. Hence, neither max power nor max torque are what decide anything. The power/torque vs rpm is what is important. And power/torque are not mutually independent.

Comment: I’ve always assumed that the driver’s understanding of the power/torque curve and the gear ratios of their particular car, combined with their skill and sense of timing, would also be a factor in which car wins. Perhaps the asker is trying to ask, “which car gives more of an edge to the driver?”, but the literal question of which car will **win** seems to go beyond the vehicle alone.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I am assuming all other external variables like driver's understanding, skill, timing etc.  are equal for both cases. Obviously if driver's are drastically different levels, then it would matter, but i am quite sure, that is not the intention of the OP.

Comment: @wanderer Of course, it's true: The gearbox designer selects a power range at the wheels that they want to achieve, and designs the gear ratios to fit. That power range has its top value at the engine's max power point, and its bottom value at some fraction of that power which the gearbox designer is willing to accept as a trade off for fewer gears. As such, the entire power range at the wheels depends almost exclusively on the max power that the engine can deliver. It does not matter that the power at the wheels has some waviness, the range it occupies derives from the max power input.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica " _That power range has its top value at the engine's max power point_ "  No, the top value of the power range is some point beyond the engine's max power. This is also why the max power is not the be all and end all. " _As such, the entire power range at the wheels depends almost exclusively on the max power that the engine can deliver._ " Almost , but not entirely. It depends on the power across the range of rpm that the engine will operate in during the gear shifts.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica " _It does not matter that the power at the wheels has some waviness, the range it occupies derives from the max power input._ "
The range it occupies will be a range that includes rpms below and above the max power rpm. Which is my point, that the peak/max power is not the be all and end all. The power across the range of rpm matters. A car can have lower peak power, but still have higher power across enough of the rpm range, to beat the car with higher peak power.

Comment: @wanderer I tried to make my line or reasoning clear to you, and I'm sorry that I failed to make it clear enough. However, I'm at a loss how I could make it any clearer. As such, I beg you to reread carefully what I have written, and try to understand my thought process. Because otherwise, this discussion is going nowhere and we'll just keep talking past each other.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Same goes the other way round. i have failed to make myself clear as well. You might want to write a new answer if you really feel that strongly that you are correct. . And elaborate on your point of view, You wont have the word limit of the comments

Comment: Well, I would do so if there wasn't already an answer that satisfied me. The way it is, I've cast my votes appropriately, and left a comment here to point out the crucial missing point in this answer, imho. I just don't believe in posting answers similar to already existing ones; when I write an answer, I require it to contain stuff that noone else has brought up yet. And when I don't have enough new stuff to contribute, I'd rather help making the existing answers better. I believe that's a) more kind to our readers, and b) gives the authors the existing answers a chance of learning.

Comment: " _I've cast my votes appropriately, and left a comment here to point out the crucial missing point in this answer_ "
Yes, you have cast your votes according to what you think is correct and others have cast their votes as well according to what they think is correct. That is indeed how it is supposed to work.

" _And when I don't have enough new stuff to contribute, I'd rather help making the existing answers better._ "
Okay, cool. You have said where you disagree with my answer, and i have told you why i think you are wrong. I am sure you think I am wrong. i dont know what more to say.

Comment: There is one last thing about this site, that people usually do not appreciate enough when they are new to it, I certainly learned it only over the years of contributing: High voted answers, correct answers, and helpful answers are not necessarily the same. High voted answers are usually a) the first *sensible looking* answer and b) answers that reflect common "wisdom". Note that correctness is not on the list. I've seen this effect over and over again: A high ranked and/or accepted answer that was vastly inferior to a lower ranked answer, *just because the better answer was late to the party*

Comment: I have myself sometimes deleted my own, positively ranked answers, just because a single person proved to me that my answer was wrong. And it is exactly those persons that have taught me the most on this site. The point is, there is no reason to be confident in the quality of a well received answer, unless you can follow its reasoning and find that its conclusion is sound. The votes are a good indicator what answers *might* be helpful, but this indicator may be wrong. High ranked answers attract votes mainly because they are already high ranked, and thus read more often.

Comment: Want to expand this answer to point out the effects of weight and traction?  The question does not seem to assume they are equal and they may be impacted by the gearing choices, etc... It may be worth addressing CVT and electric vehicles as well.

Comment: @ttbek I am just assuming ideal ceteris paribus conditions, i.e. weight is same for both cars, traction is not the limiting factor and is same for both cars.  Electric vehicles are a completely different discussion. OP is asking about cars with internal combustion engines. I also feel OP is asking about standard cars with the standard transmission rather than CVTs . He is talking about drag race. I dont think CVTs are used in drag races, there is too much power loss in CVTs

Answer (score 6):

Car A will win, if it has the right final drive ratio. *Power* is (torque x RPM) so an engine with high power but low torque develops its power at high RPM. Once you gear it down appropriately, it will win the race.

Comment: Correct answer. There is not more to it than that. All technical details are extraneous to the problem. You want to increase an object's kinetic energy? Then what you need is energy.

Comment: thank you @Peter-ReinstateMonica

Comment: It is not only the final drive ratio. The full gear ratios (final drive + gearbox) are important. And... one can win the race with lower final kinetic energy if the most acceleration is at the start.

Comment: Impossible to tell, because there are so many other factors involved.  To consider an extreme case, which vehicle wins a drag race between a bicycle and a 100-car freight train?  The train has far more power, but it has to accelerate far more mass, and do it with wheels that have a relatively poor coefficient of friction.

Comment: @fraxinus Ahhhh... well. Yes, true. It is about the covered overall distance, not the final speed. Darn, it is a bit more complicated ;-).

Comment: @jamesqf Yeah, well, *[ceteris paribus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus).* I mean, the Saturn V would lose the race even though its energy/time output is that of England. (But then, it was not kinetic energy anyway, but still.)

Answer (score 5):

The single power or torque number does not tell the whole story.
You need to know the power band of each engine which is a graph that tells you the power/torque provided at each value of rpm.

[image]

The higher powered car can still  fall behind the lower powered car if the lower powered car is able to provide its power/torque across a wider range of rpms.

Answer (score 1):

Torque is a fetish for solving the transmission non-idealities.

The power wins the race. But it is not the maximal power of the engine, it is the average power output of the engine for a given type of competition.

One can easilly find a truck or even a tractor with a mind-boggling (from a racng cart viewpoint) engine torque and a medicore (from a racing car viewpoint) engine power. A race between a car and a truck is usually pointless. Tractors are not better.

If one dives into the math of the acceleration, one will find that the acceleration is proportional to the torque *at the wheels*. This is not the same as the torque at the engine flywheel.

There is a transmission in between.

And if one assumes that the transmission is loseless (or has a constant efficiency which is almost true) it boils down to maximizing the engine power.

And now we find that the engine is not that simple. It has its maximal power at some rpm and less at both higher and lower rpm. The driver has to switch gears in order to keep the engine near its maximum power rpm.

The gearbox may have its gear ratios widely spaced and the driver will switch gears less frequently, leaving the engine more time away from its maximum. On the other hand, the time needed for switching gears will be less (and the time used for switching gears is lost for the acceleration).

And here, a high-torque engine may help. Somewhat.

High maximal torque is a "proxy" for a wide power peak at power vs rpm graph. It is not a good criteria, as any atmospheric diesel engine will tell you, but it is a good proxy for the performance of a similar engines in the acceleration.

Other than that, torque is just a design parameter for the transmission.

If you have the whole graph of power vs vehicle speed at different gears, the maximal torque doesn't carry any meaning.

Comment: "And if one assumes that the transmission is loseless (or has a constant efficiency which is almost true) it boils down to maximizing the engine power."  But I think this is often quite far from true outside of continuously variable transmissions or electric vehicles, no?

Comment: No. Don't know about CVTs, but the traditional manuals have more or less constant efficiency per gear and no much of a difference between gears. Except when you have a direct gear that has almost no loss (but it exists only in rear-driven or more traditional 4x4 cars).

Comment: Really?  I'm no expert in this, but https://www.schaeffler.com/remotemedien/media/_shared_media/08_media_library/01_publications/schaeffler_2/symposia_1/downloads_11/6_Transmission_Systems_1.pdf  Seems to show 1st gear vary by almost 10%, that just doesn't seem anywhere near 'more or less constant' efficiency to me... just 'less'.  Of course this kind of language is subjective though.  5th gear has small variation, sure, but it is massively different from 1st gear... not what I would call "no much of a difference."  But I'm not a car person... maybe I'm misreading this or it is unreliable?

Comment: @ttbek The article is profoundly biased towards automatic transmissions. The 5-speed manual transmission shown there has 5th direct and this is why it is that much more efficient than 1st. They don't show 2,3 and 4 but I think they will be only somewhat better than 1st. And then, that much variation in efficiency vs speed is something new to me, probably because of lubrication peculiarities of this particular gearbox. Also, note the "partial load" phrase - it is related to the ordinary street performance and not a competition (i.e. maximum power) workload. This distorts the picture, too.

Comment: What exactly is meant by constant efficiency in this context ? I would assume it to be referring to friction losses, but you have already mentioned separately transmission is lossless. So, what exactly do you mean by constant efficiency ?

Comment: @fraxinus  They do get into intermediate gears in more detail, see figure 12.  I'm also not sure why you think it is so biased in favor of automatics when they include things like figure 10.  It seems like a balanced and factual overview.  In retrospect, I think the figures are for fuel efficiency, not power transfer efficiency.  https://www.nap.edu/read/21744/chapter/7#172 claims about 4 and 13% transmission loss for manual and a conventional automatic respectively.  Still numbers I wouldn't consider negligible, but certainly much more in line with what you have said.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_torque claims "Effective torque will often be 5-15% lower than the shaft or crank ratings of an engine due to a loss through the drivetrain."  but without citation.

Comment: To clarify, having done a bit more reading I think your answer is good.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-MH4sf5xkY and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt7iUBE3_AE also helped my understanding.  
@wanderer I think by the constant efficiency, he means that whatever the loss is when we don't assume it is lossless, e.g. 5%, in the drivetrain, that it isn't very different at a different rpm.

Comment: @ttbek " _whatever the loss is when we don't assume it is lossless, e.g. 5%, in the drivetrain, that it isn't very different at a different rpm_ " If that is what it means, then i also agree, that is not a very unreasonable assumption